# как сделать чтобы при создании файла в вс код автоматически предлагалось какое расширение у файла

Tags: visual-studio-code

Подскажите, при создании файла в вс код автоматически предлагал выбрать какое расширение у файла, сдуру нажал случайно не показывать это, теперь не могу найти как включить. Подскажите, где, что нужно включить?

Comment: Добро пожваловать! Добавьте больше информации, каким образом вы создаете файл. Просто вариантов некоторое количество и сейчас не понятно, что вы имеете в виду

Comment: Файл-> Новый файл. после этого в рабочей области открывался новый файл и появлялось списком поле ассоциации типа файла, ну js, css и т.д. А сбоку от этого списка там было что-то типа не показывать,  я нажал, и теперь не могу выбрать сразу расширение для файла  и не могу в этой же строке переименовать файл

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! чтобы дополнить вопрос, нажмите [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

По добавленной информации, при создании файла можно добавить ассоциацию при помощи горячих клавиш

1. `File` -> `New file`
2. Нажать вместе <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, а затем отдельно только <kbd>M</kbd>
3. Появится строка с выбором языка ассоциации с новым файлом

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Либо чтобы вернуть все в первоначальное состояние

1. <kbd>F1</kbd> -> в строке написать settings
2. выбрать `Preferences: Open User Settings`
3. Далее в строку с поиском настроек ввести `Untitled:`
4. Изменить `hidden` на `text` у настройки `Workbench › Editor › Untitled: Hint`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо, вернул в прежнее состояние

Comment: @rev на здоровье. Обратите внимание на данную тему [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)